# How to implement the following nested SQL as Lambda Statement

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, lambda

I have the following nested SQL Statement and i will to do the same using Lambda statement in C# How do i do it?

SQL:

```
SELECT board.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) from discussion_topic
                 WHERE TopicBoardID=board.BoardID) as TopicCount
FROM `discussion_board` as board
```

This is the structure of my 2 tables

```
Table Name: discussion_board
Fields:
BoardID
BoardName
BoardCreatedBy
BoardCreatedDate

Table Name: discussion_topic
Fields:
TopicID
TopicName
TopicCreatedBy
TopicCreatedDate
TopicBoardID
```

just 2 simple tables with no Forign Keys,

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you a new anonymous type which will have the board record and the count of discussion topics.

```
var result = dataContext.Board.Select(x => new {x, Count = x.DiscussionTopics.Count()});
```

You could simply use `board.DiscussionTopics.Count();` on each record to get the count.  No need to do the above really, if i understand your question correctly

**UPDATE**

If you have no foreign keys then this might do it

```
var result = dataContext.Board.Select(x => new {x, Count = dataContext.DiscussionTopics.Count(d => d.TopicBoardId == x.BoardID)});
```

Comment: there are 2 different tables here discussion_topic and discussion_board so board.DiscusionTopic.Count wouldn't work right?

Comment: If you have a foreign key between board and discussion_topic then your board EF class will have a collection of discussion_topics so no reason why you can't.

Comment: Ah, it will make life a lot easier if you do.  I'd recommend you start using them. They make data management far far easier and the whole EF will do most of the hard work for you

Comment: Check out: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/

Comment: unfortunately i cannot change anything in the schema :( i just need to use the DB as they gave me

Comment: No probs. Glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

```
from b in DataContext.Boards
select new {
    BoardId = b.BoardID,
    BoardName = b.BoardName,
    BoardCreatedBy = b.BoardCreatedBy,
    BoardCreateDate = b.BoardCreateDate,
    TopicCount = Discussions.Count(d => d.TopicBoardId == b.BoardID)
}
```